# Ruby: Singleton method of an instance variable inside a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, accessor, singleton-methods

I am taking ruby-kickstart (Josh Cheek) challenges and even though I managed to pass all the test there is one thing I cannot understand.

In the exercise you are being asked to override the << method for an instance variable. Specifically here is what you have to do:

> In Ruby on Rails, when a person goes to a URL on your site, your
>   application looks at the url,   and maps it to a controller method to
>   handle the request
>
> My boss wanted to be able to specify what CSS class the body of the
>   HTML output should have,  based on which controller method was being
>   accessed.  It fell to me to provide a method, which, when invoked,
>   would return a String that could handle the request    There are a few
>   nuances, though.  The String you return must be retained during the
>   object's entire life  The method must be able to be called multiple
>   times  The String you return should know how to add new classes: each
>   class is separated by a space  The only method you need to worry about
>   being invoked is the << method.
>    (plus a few other irrelevant things)
>    EXAMPLE:

```
controller = ApplicationController.new   
controller.body_class                  
#=> ""    
controller.body_class << 'admin'    
controller.body_class     
#=> "admin"   
controller.body_class << 'category'    
controller.body_class        
#=> "admin category"    
controller.body_class << 'page' << 'order'    
controller.body_class                  
#=> "admin category page order"
```

My working solution:

```
class ApplicationController 

  def initialize
    @body_class = ""
  end

  def body_class
    def @body_class.<<(str)
      puts "self is:"+self
      return self if self=~/\b#{Regexp.escape(str)}\b/
      if self==""
        self.concat(str)
      else
        self.concat(" ")
        self.concat(str)
      end
    end

    return @body_class
  end
end
```

Everything works perfectly fine. 
But an earlier solution I gave (and it didn't work) was the following

```
class ApplicationController 
  attr_accessor :body_class
  def initialize
    @body_class = ""
  end

  def @body_class.<<(str)
    puts "self is:"+self
    return self if self=~/\b#{Regexp.escape(str)}\b/


    if self==""
      self.concat(str)
    else
      self.concat(" ")
      self.concat(str)
    end

  end

  def body_class                #Even this for the way I work it out on my mind is unnecessary 
    return @body_class
  end



end
```

When someone runs on the second not-working sollution the following

```
obj = ApplicationController.new
obj.body_class << "Hi"
```

The << method is not being overridden by the object's singleton. 
I do not understand why I have to wrap the singleton methods inside the body_class method. (Mind that in the second solution there is an attr_accessor.

Could anyone enlighten me please! 
Thanks!

Comment: On another note you might want to consider what that regex does. Many frameworks use css styles like `message`, `message-important`, `message-warning` and a hyphen will be treated as a word boundary so if `@body_class` is `"admin-log"` and you then want to append `log` or `admin` that will not happen

Comment: Hi @engineersmnky,
Thanks for your comments. This example is from a beginner’s tutorial to learn the ruby's basics. There are challenges that are being checked by rspec. I don't thing that the code is intended to work on a real app :) The tutorial can be found [here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/ruby-kickstart)

Answer (score 4):

> I do not understand why I have to wrap the singleton methods inside the body_class method.

To access the correct instance variable. When you attempt to override it outside of method, you're in the class context. This code runs at class load time. No instances have been created yet. (And even if instances did exist at this point, `@body_class` instance variable belongs to class `ApplicationController`, which is itself an instance of class `Class`).

You need instance context.

---

Also I am pretty sure that this problem can be solved without any method patching voodoo. Just provide a different object (conforming to the same API. This is called "duck typing").

```
class ApplicationController

  def body_class
    @body_class ||= CompositeClass.new
  end

  class CompositeClass
    def initialize
      @classes = []
    end

    def <<(new_class)
      @classes << new_class
    end

    # I imagine, this is what is ultimately called on ApplicationController#body_class,
    # when it's time to render the class in the html.
    def to_s
      @classes.join(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

Didn't test this code, naturally.

Comment: Delegating to an array is nice. I actually doubt there is a need in `CompositeClass`, just delegate to a native `Array` and provide kinda `build_class_string` method.

Comment: @mudasobwa: feel free to offer an improvement in your answer :)

Comment: I am all in monkeypatching! I even refuse to refine!

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev !!

Comment: I prefer this composition over a singleton method especially when that singleton method overrides an existing documented method `String#<<`. Notable difference though is that `String#<<` and `String#concat` when given an integer will convert it to a character where as your solution will just convert it to a `String` on output (`#to_s`). What I am really interested in is how does one unnaturally test code? ;)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the proper way to do it is to explicitly `extend` the instance variable:

```
class A
  attr_reader :body_class
  def initialize
    @body_class = "".extend(Module.new do
      def <<(other)
        return self if self[/\b#{Regexp.escape(other)}\b/]
        concat(' ') unless empty?
        concat(other)
      end
    end)    
  end  
end
```